# Interaction between JSP and External javascript files

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, web-applications, web

I am newbie to external javascript files (*.js). Basically I have my JSP ready but my manager wants me to add graphics in it.

So I found some *.js files. But I don't know how to communicate between them and my JSP page.

I want to pass data from jsp to external .js file. 
Is there any mechanism to do that?

For e.g:-

**Demo.jsp**

```
out.print(request.getAttribute("Name"));
```

Now I want use/pass/set above value to **main.js** file how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJavascriptVariable = <%= request.getParameter("Name")%>;
                                     //or .getAttribute("Name")
</script>
```

This could do the trick, it will make a global Variable which could be accessed in main.js. When you have GET Parameters you could also use only JS:

```
var paramarr = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
var params = {};

for (var i = 0; i < paramarr.length; i++) {
    var tmparr = paramarr[i].split("=");
    params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
}
```

or a bit shorter:

```
var params = {};
// parse URL's GET parameters and iterate over them
window.location.search.substr(1).split("&"),forEach(function(el) {
    var kv = el.split('"'); // split into [ key, value ] array
    params[kv[0]] = kv[1];
});
```

Now you can access the parameter in JS via:

```
params['name']
```

Personally I would use AJAX (e.g. with the help of JQuery) to get Data for my JavaScript files, you can look at that at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/ (2018 edit: kust use native ajax calls or whatever JS framework is hyped this week ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ***.js*** file you can't write jsp sriptlet in it.
If you need to call value in **.js** file there is one simple way.
**Assign values to** input elements in .jsp page.(If you are not using values in .jsp page assign values to **hidden input elements**)
Then include.js file in your .jsp page
get values as javasript or jquery methods.

Ex:-

```
value= document.getElementById("element_id").value
```

**OR** If you are using **jquery** you can get as

```
value = $("#element_id").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global js variable and assign the value.

```
  <% String myValue =  (String)request.getAttribute("Name"); %> 



    var global1 ='<%= myValue  %>';
```

Comment: could you be more specific. I mean.. the line you mentioned above should I add it in .jsp file and then I can use "global1" in any .js file?

Comment: Yes,the variable should be global and those js files should be add in jsp  file.

Comment: I have tried it. But whenever use "var global1 ='<%= myValue  %>';" my page goes blank. But when I do "var global1 =1" it works. Why  this is happening?